# assign variable to ajax responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to load the text content of a file into a variable using ajax.

The function readFile() seems to works fine. I think the issue is that my file, 'countries.csv' is big and taking too long to load, so `console.log(x)` just returns '`undefined`'

```
// last argument in open() is async; must be true or else chrome gives an error

function readFile(file) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', file, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var fileContent = xhr.responseText;
      // console.log(fileContent); <-- this line would work just fine
      return fileContent;
    }
  }
  xhr.send(null);
}


// so this next line takes some time to run
var x = readFile('/data/countries.csv');

// and this line runs before the last line is done
console.log(x);
```

What can I do to load the content of the file 'countries.csv' into the variable x before I start actually working with the variable x?

Am I missing some kind of event listener?

Comment: why not use fetch() api, ajax is async, when console.log is excuted the file isn't there yet

Comment: `return fileContent` is returning to the `onreadystatechange` function. `fetch` is the easiest way around this

Comment: returning a value in onreadystatechange doesn't return anything anywhere. onreadystatechange is called asynchronously.

Comment: don't be fooled, fetch wont help if you do not understand asynchrony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback :)

Try

```
function readFile(file, cb) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', file, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var fileContent = xhr.responseText;
      return cb(fileContent);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(null);
}

readFile('/data/countries.csv', thing => console.log(thing));
```

Here's some extra stuff to learn more about callback/async programming in javascript: http://www.learn-js.org/en/Callbacks

Comment: i looked a bit into this callback business before accepting your answer; it actually helped me resolve another pickle i'd come across (doing multiple ajax requests in one go) so this is quite exciting

Comment: It makes me extremely happy to hear that. Great stuff. :)